# Use regexp on two variables using tcl

Tags: tcl

I have two variables

```
echo $a
>> 123.txt
echo $b
>> 341.txt 123.txt 654.txt
```

I want to use regexp to find whether a is present in b!

Comment: Why do you want to use regexp? What are the cases where a standard [list search](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) or [string match](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) will not be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl's `regexp` let's you provide a special prefix in a regular expression to say that the rest of the RE is a literal string. That makes doing this easy (providing you don't want anchoring):

```
if {[regexp ***=$a $b]} {
    puts "found!"
}
```

The `***=` prefix, if present, must be the first four characters of the RE.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if {$a in $b} {
    puts present
} else {
    puts absent
}
```

`in` is described in the [`expr` man page](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm).

Or with regexp, this:

```
if {[regexp -- "\\m[regsub -all {\W} $a {\\&}]\\M" [join $b]]} {
    puts present
} else {
    puts absent
}
```

All that complication is to ensure you don't match "123-txt" or "0123.txt" or "123.txt2"